# Mock Injected private variable in Activity

Tags: android, junit, mockito, dagger-2, android-livedata

```
class CustomActivity : BaseActivity() {

@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProviderFactory

private val mViewModel: SplashViewModel by viewModels {
    viewModelFactory
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    observeOrderResponse()
}

private fun observeOrderResponse() {
    mViewModel.userObserver.observe(this) { userResponse ->
        updateUIBasedOnUserResponse(userResponse)
    }
}
```

}

Here in this code I want to mock `userObserver(LiveData<UserResponse>)` with specific UserResponse. How can I mock the observer where my viewmodel is injected?

I can not use AppComponentFactory as my min sdk value is 26.

Answer (score 0):

```
val viewModel : SplashViewModel = mockk()
// or you need to Mock Your ViewModelFactory
@Test
fun myTest(){
   val fakeObserver = MutableLiveData<UserResponse>()
   every {viewModel.userObserver } returns fakeObserver
   fakeObserver.value = // put you data that you want to observe
}
```

Comment: How can I mock ViewModelFactory which is injected like above with @Inject?